# Errors during angularfire2 installation and setup

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I followed [Angularfire2 Installation and Setup](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md) (08-21-2016) but I receive errors in the terminal when I type:

```
ng build
```

These are the errors:

```
Build error
The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler] failed with:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
    at Object.parse (native)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler._loadTsConfig (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\broccoli-typescript.js:128:25)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler._createServiceHost (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\broccoli-typescript.js:163:25)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.build (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\broccoli-typescript.js:41:12)
    at C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\index.js:152:21
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1198:9)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.Plugin (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\broccoli-plugin\index.js:10:31)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler.CachingWriter [as constructor] (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\broccoli-caching-writer\index.js:21:10)
    at BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\broccoli-typescript.js:27:10)
    at Angular2App._getTsTree (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\angular2-app.js:331:18)
    at Angular2App._buildTree (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\angular2-app.js:124:23)
    at new Angular2App (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\lib\broccoli\angular2-app.js:53:23)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\angular-cli-build.js:10:10)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:55:19)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.init (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\builder.js:89:10)
    at new Class (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\core-object\core-object.js:18:12)
    at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\tasks\serve.js:15:19)
    at C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\commands\serve.js:64:24
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\ng_cli\test_cli_fire\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1198:9)
```

Modified files: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/461

Repository: https://github.com/sorcamarian/angularfire2-instalation-errors


Have I done something wrong or it is a bug?


Thank you

Comment: Do you have to stay with angularfire2 2.0.0-beta.2? Because the current one is beta4 but it require Angular2 RC5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because many [have encountered this issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/461), a couple of people posted some solutions.

I managed to find the best solution for me and I [created a repository](https://github.com/sorcamarian/angularfire2-instalation-webpack-fixed-errors).

Answer (score 2):

I forked your repo and got stuck at `npm install`, due to incompatibility with the current angularfire2 beta5.

Since your app seems pretty much empty, my suggestion is to start from scratch and follow the latest angularfire2 instruction. It was updated today(8/29).

Comment: I started from scratch with the latest angularfire2(webpack), but the error message: "Cannot find name 'firebase'." still appears. 
Multiple people have the same issue. Please take a look at this post: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/461

Comment: @Marian07 If you can update your repo, I can try again.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I found the solution.